# ROS Answers SE migration: rviz vs vtk

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a to create a new vizualizer for a robot related project. While I have solid experience with OpenGL, that experience points to there being a productivity gain from using a toolkit. The decision comes down to rviz, or VTK.

The vizualizer will need to be:

- embed-able in other applications
- middleware agnostic
- displays will renders, there seems to be more to leverage from VTK

To be honest, from what I see there is very little I can leverage from rviz. What I may want to leverage have ties to the "ros way" of doing things which conflict with being middleware agnostic. VTK also seems to have a larger set of components, and potential power.

Thoughts?

Related, can ogre and VTK play together in the same app? (i.e. if someone wanted to make an rviz plugin for a VTK based component)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40310/rviz-vs-vtk/) by [Bob Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2328/bob-dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

VTK is a better approach for ROS-agnostic visualization.

I believe VTK uses OGRE, itself.

If you later want to integrate your tool into a ROS system, you might consider the [new rqt framework](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt), which is designed to be easier to plug into than rviz.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2